# Disable github cache for internal teamcity build status image in README.md

Tags: github, teamcity, github-api, teamcity-8.0

I have a TeamCity Build Status Icon in github README.md which looks as follows

```
[![Build Status](http://<internal-tc-server>:8111/app/rest/builds/buildType:(id:BuildID)/statusIcon)](http://<internal-tc-server>/viewType.html?buildTypeId=BuildID&guest=1)
```

Looks like Github caches the images in README.md and the new image src url looks as follows.

```
<img src="https://github-camo.global.ssl.fastly.net/xxx/yyy"/>
```

Since the teamcity url is within our internal network, github will not be able to access it and cant cache it properly. So, I don't see any image in the README. Is there any Image tag that I can use to disable the automatic github image caching?

Comment: Disabling the CDN is not possible currently: https://github.com/blog/1766-proxying-user-images. However, you might consider exposing the image via a public endpoint which doesn't require authentication, but uses unguessable tokens instead (e.g. `https://<public_server>/images/<build_id>?token=<random_token>`).

Comment: Any luck since 2014? :)

Comment: This situation sucks and means that we cannot have a status badge while our build server remains off the internet.

Answer (score 0):

It is an old question, but because there are still answers to it:
Github has now a possibility to handle their camo cache.
https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/about-anonymized-urls

If you are able to set the `Cache-Control` header to `no-cache` Github should ignore the image for caching. But this does not work for private Networks as Github has documented it here: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/about-anonymized-urls#viewing-images-on-private-networks